# Can't get a basic SP2010 Modal to work

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I'm migrating a project from SP2007 to SP2010. I want to get a modal popup to work, to open up the New Item window of a list from an aspx page. I can't get the modal to work in the most basic example, and I can't figure out what's going on.

I keep getting the following error if I use Developer Tools and enable Script Debugging:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarSelector' cannot be converted to type 'Sys.IDisposable'.
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Language="javascript" Name="../ProjectFolder/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" Defer="false" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Language="javascript" Name="../ProjectFolder/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" Defer="false" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink4" Language="javascript" Name="../MicrosoftAjax.js" Defer="false" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink5" Language="javascript" Name="../SP.debug.js" Defer="false" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink6" Language="javascript" Name="../SP.UI.Dialog.js" Defer="false" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenInDialog(title, url) {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.title = title;
        options.width = 680;
        options.height = 500;
        options.url = url;
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, ConfirmationCallback);
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    function ConfirmationCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
        if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {

        }
    }


    OpenInDialog('test', 'http://portal.dev.loc/sites/TestSite/_layouts/Test.aspx');

</script>
```

I keep thinking that the problem is related to SP.UI.Dialog.js, but my reference is correct, and I can't figure out why it isn't working. This is driving me nuts. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you posted this question on the http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Good idea. Just did it here:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44548/cant-get-a-basic-modal-to-work-on-2010

Comment: You see? Your question already got more traction on that specific community site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Now I just need to figure out the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a race condition that wasn't solved by putting the method call in $(document).ready, which I had tried before (not sure why I didn't have it in this example).

I was trying to just do a simple modal, but made it too simple. Trying to open a modal immediately when the page was opened didn't work. Moving the exact same method call to a button worked fine. None of the Scriptlinks were necessary. All the jquery libraries were already provided on the page by SharePoint.

I knew it would be something stupid. Thanks Vardhaman, for leading me in the right direction.

Also, Vardhaman's answer here worked:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44548/cant-get-a-basic-modal-to-work-on-2010/44687#comment41263_44687

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

```
OpenInDialog('test', 'http://portal.dev.loc/sites/TestSite/_layouts/Test.aspx');
```

},"sp.ui.dialog.js");

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on something similar recently, so to clarify the code even more, try with the following approach:

```
    function OpenInDialog(title, url) {
            var options = {
                title: title,
                width: 680,
                height: 500,
                url: url,
                dialogReturnValueCallback: ConfirmationCallback
            };

            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }

    function ConfirmationCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
        if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    OpenInDialog('test', 'http://portal.dev.loc/sites/TestSite/_layouts/Test.aspx');
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I've tried it that way too. The problem has to be related to not including the correct libraries or something. I know my script is correct. I just can't figure out which libraries I'm missing, and why they aren't already included, since this is a SharePoint page.